# how can I transform Perl's $1 special variable to Python?

Tags: python, perl, zoneminder

I want to transform a hash that contains hashes in perl to python. here is a piece of its perl code:

```
our %types = (
  string => {
    db_type     => 'string',
    hint        => 'string',
    pattern     => qr|^(.+)$|,
    format      => q( $1 )
  },
  boolean => {
    db_type     => 'boolean',
    hint        => 'yes|no',
    pattern     => qr|^([yn])|i,
    check       => q( $1 ),
    format      => q( ($1 =~ /^y/) ? 'yes' : 'no' )
  }
)
```

here is how I wrote it in Python:

```
types = [
    'string': {
        'db_type': 'string',
        'hint': 'string',
        'pattern': re.compile(r'^(.+)$'),
        # 'format':,
    },
    'boolean': {
        'db_type': 'boolean',
        'hint': 'yes|no',
        'pattern': re.compile(r'^([yn])', re.IGNORECASE),
        #'check': HOW SHOULD I TRANSFORM THIS PART?,
        #'format': HOW SHOULD I TRANSFORM THIS PART?,
    },
]
```

I don't know how should I transform the **values of format and check keys**.
any help is apperciated.

Comment: What does `$1` *do*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036285/what-does-1-mean-in-perl

Comment: I guess you'd make this a *function* that returns a dictionary containing those parts, then.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there isn't a way I can do it in place, just like Perl?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "in place". Python and Perl are fundamentally different languages, you can't use the same idioms.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean in the dictionary declration.

Answer (score 1):

The $1 is the portion of text that exists in the first parentheses of the evaluated regular expression.

You need to rewrite the whole mechanism, but something like 
`.group(1)` for `$1` and also

```
"yes" if object.group(1) == "y" else "no"
```

for

```
($1 =~ /^y/) ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

should do the job.